# Azure Multiple VMS provisioning through templates using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I have used azuredeploy.json as the starting template, replaced all variables based on the inputs to the powershell. dynamically created JSONs for multiple VMS and given that json files  as the input for New-AzureRmResourceGroupdeloyment.

$dynamictemplateURI = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Dynamictemplate$i.json"
$json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 999 | Out-File $dynamictemplateURI
 New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deployName -ResourceGroupName $RGName -TemplateUri $dynamictemplateURI

So, I am getting multiple dynamictemplates for multiple VMs. But my task is to group all templates under a master template and to give that master template path in dynamictemplateURL,  Please help,,

Comment: Is their any command in powershell to group all these templates into a master template?

Comment: here i need to merge all templates in one master template and to give that path in new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment command? please someone help me?

Comment: This question is more suitable on Serverfault. It's about Azure VM provisioning, not programming.